# application/octet-stream JPG to PDF image conversion failure using Imagick?

Tags: php, pdf, jpeg, imagick

I have a web app which is used to upload multiple JPGs, PNGs, and PDFs. It has been working fine for a while, but every now and then a user will upload a file that my code doesn't like, which is the case now. The mime type of this particular file is `application/octet-stream`.

Once the user has uploaded all their files, my app converts all the files to PDFs using Imagick. My code below is returning `true` and throwing no errors:

```
    $image = $this->unconvertedImagesDir . $this->userID .  "_" . $uploadNum . ".jpg";
    $imageMagick = new Imagick($image);
    //shrink file size:
    $imageMagick->resizeImage(700, 0, null, TRUE);

    $convert = $imageMagick->setimageformat('pdf');

    if($convert)
    {
        $moveFile = file_put_contents($this->PDFsDir . $this->userID . "_" . $uploadNum . ".pdf", $imageMagick);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

However, when I try to open the newly converted PDF Acrobat gives me this message:

```
An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem.
```

And then the file is just blank.

Does anyone know why Imagick is messing up this PDF conversion?

**UPDATE:** Yesterday the `mimeType` was showing up as `application/octet-stream` but now today it is showing as `image/jpeg`. I was also able to successfully convert the image on my Vagrant machine running ImageMagick 6.6.8-7 and PHP 5.4 however the problem remains on my Staging and Production servers running ImageMagick 6.4.3 and PHP 5.3.

Comment: So you are passing an octet-stream but telling ImageMagick that it is a JPEG file?

Comment: Yes. The file type is JPEG and the MIME type is octet-stream.

Comment: So, say the troublesome file is called `image.jpg`, what happens if you run `file image.jpg` and `identify image.jpg`. `file` is a standard Unix tool for guessing file types and `identify` is part of the ImageMagick suite in case you are not familiar.

Comment: `JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02`